# wix4: add EULA, confiration at end of install

Tags: windows, installation, wix4

I installed Firegiant HeatWave for VS2022 so I can create a wix installer in Visual Studio 2022.  I am using the 'MSI Package (Wix v4)' project type.

I am able to create an .msi which will install all my files, but I want to add a EULA (with checkbox) and some confirmation that the install was completed successfully.

How can I modify my .wxs file (or do whatever is needed) to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/wixext/wixui/ has the answers:

To add a WixUI dialog set to your MSI package:

- Add a reference to the WixToolset.UI.wixext WiX extension.
- Add the WixToolset.UI.wixext WiX extension namespace to your WiX authoring.
- Add the WixUI element to your WiX authoring.

For example:

```xml
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
  xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui">

  <Package ...>
      ...
      <ui:WixUI
        Id="WixUI_InstallDir"
        InstallDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
        />
  </Package>
</Wix>
```

Comment: getting this error:
WIX0200 The Package element contains an unhandled extension element 'WixUI'. Please ensure that the extension for elements in the 'http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui' namespace has been provided.

Do these reference/extension come from nuget or such?

Comment: `Add a reference to the WixToolset.UI.wixext WiX extension.` is from NuGet.